# How can I get python ''.encode('unicode_escape') to return escape codes for ascii?

Tags: python, unicode, unicode-escapes

I am trying to use the `encode` method of python strings to return the unicode escape codes for characters, like this:

```
>>> print( 'ф'.encode('unicode_escape').decode('utf8') )
\u0444
```

This works fine with non-ascii characters, but for ascii characters, it just returns the ascii characters themselves:

```
>>> print( 'f'.encode('unicode_escape').decode('utf8') )
f
```

The desired output would be `\u0066`. This script is for pedagogical purposes.

How can I get the unicode hex codes for ALL characters?

Comment: what else do you expect `'f`' to return?

Comment: You can't. `unicode_escape` will never escape printable ASCII characters. What are you trying to do here? In other words, what is the *actual goal*?

Comment: @MartijnPieters See edits above. The script is for pedagogical purposes, and the output for `f` would be `\u0066`.

Comment: So what about non-BMP codepoints? Should the output be Python string-literal compatible, or are you aiming for, say, JSON-compatible output? This matters; Python would use `\Uhhhhhhh` (8 hex digits), JSON would use a UTF-16 surrogate pair. And if you aim for Python compatibility, why not `\xhh` for Latin-1 bytes?

Comment: @MartijnPieters For my purposes, I can assume that everything will be in the BMP. I am aiming for 4-digit codes compatible with python string literals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ord` can be used for this, there is no need for encoding/decoding at all:

```
>>> '"\\U{:08x}"'.format(ord('f'))  # ...or \u{:04x} if you prefer
'"\\U00000066"'
>>> eval(_)
'f'
```

Comment: Thanks! The combination of `ord` and the `x` specification for hex format seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to do so manually; if you assume that all your input is within the Unicode BMP, then a straightforward regex will probably be fastest; this replaces every character with their `\uhhhh` escape:

```
import re

def unicode_escaped(s, _pattern=re.compile(r'[\x00-\uffff]')):
    return _pattern.sub(lambda m: '\\u{:04x}'.format(
        ord(m.group(0))), s)
```

I've explicitly limited the pattern to the BMP to gracefully handle non-BMP points.

Demo:

```
>>> print(unicode_escaped('foo bar ф'))
\u0066\u006f\u006f\u0020\u0062\u0061\u0072\u0020\u0444
```